# ios activity indicator is visible once, and then will not show until I try again a minute later

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous

Ok, so I have this piece of code:

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
{
    [_activity startAnimating];
    [self.searchBar bringSubviewToFront:_activity];
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    if([_activity isAnimating]){
        NSLog(@"its animating!");
    }

   dispatch_queue_t background = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

   dispatch_async(background, ^{

       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(filter:) withObject:aSearchBar.text waitUntilDone:YES];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_activity stopAnimating];
            if(![_activity isAnimating]){
                NSLog(@"its not animating anymore!");
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

what i'm trying to do is start an activity indicator which I added as a subview to the search bar. In this code, I start the animation (logging for test) on the main thread, then set up a background asynchronous thread which runs the method that generates the new data set which will reload the tableview. I wait for this to return, and which point, I stop animation and reload the tableview on the main thread.

the result is this...when the application runs, I go to the table view, and I type a word in the search bar. When I hit enter, the activity indicator shows up, the table loads, and the activity indicator stops. This is great.

Then, I click on the search bar again, start a new search, only this time, the activity indicator does not show itself, but the NSLog shows that it IS animating. The tableview reloads as expected, but no activity indicator on the UI, but based on the NSLog, it seems to working.

Finally, if I wait about a minute, and search again, it works fine. What I'm suspecting is that that the background thread is not completing maybe, and the main thread continues doing what it needs to do.

Honestly, I've been beating my head for two days now, can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a chance that this has something to do with the view hierarchy, depending on where you added the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to. If you added it directly to the search bar, it might reorganize the subviews in a way you don't expect (and move the activity indicator behind some of them, blocking it from being visible, even though it's animating.)

A good option might be to embed the search bar within a toolbar, and then have the activity indicator on the left (or right) with flexible space separating it from the search bar.